# Calculate heights for given Voltage readings [peak point - start point]

Tags: java, sorting, arraylist

Sample Input  :

8 //Array size

3 4 5 7 8 9 4 3   //voltages

Sample Output :

6 //9-3  [9 being the peak voltage and 3 being stating point]

This is the code i wrote:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;

public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int size = scan.nextInt();
        scan.nextLine();
        String input = scan.nextLine();
        String[] s = input.split(" ");

        List <Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        for(int i=0 ; i<size ; i++)
        {
            list.add(Integer.parseInt(s[i]));
        }
        list.sort(Collections.reverseOrder());

    System.out.println(list.get(0)-list.get(list.size()-1));
    //System.out.println("LAST : " +list.get(0)+"FIRST :"+list.get(list.size()-1));
    }
}
```

But this only works for a single peak.
but what if the input is anything like:

12  // array size

1 2 3 4 2 1 -1 0 2 7 5 4  //the voltages

The answer should be

First Spike :

```
Start Point = 1

Peak Point = 4

Spike height = 4 - 1 = 3.
```

Second Spike :

```
Start Point = -1

Peak Point = 7

Spike height = 7 - (-1) = 8.
```

i tried dividing the list into two lists with each part having their own peak value.

I am looking for a solution that can find any number of spikes.

Thank you!!

EDIT: --------

```
int temp = 0;
        int count = 0;
        int foo = 0;
        for(int i=0 ; i<list.size()-1 ; i++)
        {
            temp = list.get(i);
            if(list.get(i+1)-temp == 1)
            {
                count++;
            }
            else
            {
                foo++;
            }
        }
```

I tried the above, using count and foo as indexes of list :

```
System.out.println(list.get(count)-list.get(0));
System.out.println(list.get((count)+foo)-list.get(foo));
```

Comment: Sorting the values most probably is wrong in any case because I assume they are already ordered by time (i.e. when they've been taken). Thus you need to iterate over the list as is and the first value after a spike (or right at the start) is your starting point. Then you iterate until you hit the end of the spike (how would that be defined?) or the end of the input and in between you keep the highest value you've encountered. Once you've hit the end of a spike you reset your values to start a new spike.

Comment: One of the first things you should do is define how the end or start of a spike is defined. It's just a guess but I'd say once the values start to get smaller you've hit a peak and once the values start to get higher again you've hit the start of a new spike - would that be correct?

Comment: You need to keep track of the slope, whether it is ascending or descending (by comparing two elements next to each other). Starting from point 0, as long as its descending, you skip all elements. When you get to the turning point/lowest value, it is your start point. Then the reverse, you keep skipping as long as its ascending, the turning point is your peak point. Then you start all over again.

Comment: @Amongalen I m not sure , but do i need something like maps to implement it?

Comment: Please don't post that much code in a comment but [edit] your question instead.

Comment: " do i need something like maps to implement it" - no you just need to keep track of the current and the last value as well as the current direction of your slope (up or down). Then it's something like `if( last > current && direction == up) { /*you've found a peak* } else if (last < current) && direction == down) { /*you've found a start point*/ }`. This assumes there are no plateaus (where `last == current`) - if there are you need a little more logic.

Comment: @Thomas , Got it , will try and implement it. Thank You!